# How to Inherit from Generic Parent

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a parent Class

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
      //Implementation
    }
```

And I want to inherit from this class, but I can't seem to get it right,here are my attempts

```
public class CustomerRepository<Customer> : GenericRepository<Customer> 
    {
       //implementation
    }
```

Or this,

```
public class CustomerRepository<T> : GenericRepository<T> where T : new Customer()
    {

    }
```

Or this one

```
 public class CustomerRepository<T> : GenericRepository<CustomerRepository<T>> where T : CustomerRepository<T>
    {

    }
```

No matter what I do, I get this error. Please show me how I can inherit from this class, classes share the same Namespace

Error   'GenericRepository' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments CustomerRepository.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your base class has no constructor without parameters, if so the derived class must declare a.constructor and call the base class constructor with parameter.

```
class MyBase { public MyBase(object art) { } }
class Derived : MyBase {
    public Derived() : base(null) { }
 }
```

In this example if you remove the ctor from Derived you get the same error.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented a parameterless parent constructor and the it compiled. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want a non-generic class inheriting from a generic one, like this:

```
public class CustomerRepository : GenericRepository<Customer>
{
}
```

If you want this to be a generic class that narrows the type of the generic parameter (only allows `Customer` or a derived type):

```
public class CustomerRepository<T> : GenericRepository<T>
    where T : Customer
{
}
```

---

Regarding your compile-time error:

> `Error 'GenericRepository<Customer>' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`

This means exactly what it says.  You have not defined a constructor in your derived class, which means that a constructor is implicitly generated, as though you had typed this:

```
public CustomerRepository() : base() { }
```

However, the base class (`GenericRepository<Customer>`) does not have a constructor that takes no arguments.  You need to explicitly declare a constructor in the derived class `CustomerRepository` and then explicitly call a constructor on the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to repeat the type parameter in the deriving class, so:

```
public class CustomerRepository : GenericRepository<Customer> 
    {
       //implementation
    }
```

Is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried and still can't build. Same exact error. I will resart Visual Studio to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use can write as:

```
 public class CustomerRepository : GenericRepository<Customer> 
 {
        //implementation
 }
```